# Change color of border and link on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change the color of the border and the link at the same time on hover. I have tried using `border-bottom: 2px solid #000;` on `nav ul li a:hover` but the problem is that if the link is active, it stays red even on hover.

**CSS:**

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a {
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
nav ul li a.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kz1be4nm/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the cascade nature of a stylesheet, and the fact that the selectors shared the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the latter styling was overwriting it. You could change the order of the selectors like this:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hzh7ukg8/)

```
nav ul li a.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also reduce the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of `nav ul li a.active` by simply removing the element type, `a` -> `nav ul li .active`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/tugbgbdt/)

Comment: Works fine! will accept the answer when possible :)